# Creating a Linux boot drive on a MAC for a Kangaroo Mobile pC install

Tags: mac, usb, unix

I was trying to use your method to create a USB on my Mac for a Linux boot USB to install linux on a Kangaroo mobile pc.  Here is my process:
I tried this with several iterations.  My results are below.  The final result has me stopped.  Any ideas?

```
Russells-MacBook-Air:~ russellduggan$ sudo dd if=~/Desktop/linuxmint.iso of=/dev/sdx oflag=direct bs=1048576
Password:
dd: unknown operand oflag
Russells-MacBook-Air:~ russellduggan$ terminal>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
Russells-MacBook-Air:~ russellduggan$ cd terminal
-bash: cd: terminal: No such file or directory
Russells-MacBook-Air:~ russellduggan$ 
Russells-MacBook-Air:~ russellduggan$ terminal
-bash: terminal: command not found
Russells-MacBook-Air:~ russellduggan$ sudo dd if=~/Desktop/linuxmint.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=1048576
Password:
dd: /Users/russellduggan/Desktop/linuxmint.iso: No such file or directory
Russells-MacBook-Air:~ russellduggan$ sudo dd if=~/Desktop/linuxmint-18.2-cinnamon-64bit.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=1048576
dd: /dev/sdx: Operation not permitted
Russells-MacBook-Air:~ russellduggan$
```

As you can see I kind of reached an impasse at the last.  Any suggestions you might have I would appreciate.

Comment: Whose method? SE isn't threaded so we have no way of knowing what you are referring to

Answer (score 1):

In your `dd` command,

```
sudo dd if=~/Desktop/linuxmint.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=1048576
```

`/dev/sdx` for the output is incorrect.

1. This is a Linux convention, not macOS; use `/dev/diskX`.
2. X is the specific disk identifier.  If you are using instructions from a Linux site, they are most likely providing the instructions for doing this on Linux (not macOS) using X as a variable for the specific identifier since the identifier can be different for each user and/or instance as the device is removable.

In Linux it's `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc.  In macOS/BSD is `/dev/disk1`, `/dev/disk2`, etc.

Also (thanks to user3439894 via comments) you need to make sure you disk is *unmonted* but not ejected.  Do this by issuing the command `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskX` where X is the number of your disk identifier.

Comment: @user3439894 - I added your suggestion to the answer - thanks for the catch.

Comment: It's actually faster to use rdisk2 instead of disk2.